# How to stop windows keyboard icon from showing

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

i have an app that is intended for a pc with a touchscreen display. I have a built in keyboard for the app. Every time i click a textBox windows displays the icon for me to open windows keyboard. How do i disable that from poping up in my app, BUT still let it pop up outside my app?

**More info:**
I have a kiosk style app, for employees to register gas consumption. and is all made for a tactil screen. When i click either a textBox or a comboBox the icon prompting me to open windows keyboard pops up. I want to stop that from happening since the app already has a keyboard. However, employees can still get access to regular windows, so when they do i want this pop up to happen naturally on the rest of the computer. So, i just want to stop this from happening in my app, and all the solutions i have came across are for windows in generally and not app specific. **How to stop this icon from poping up in my app?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: you should give more details about your situation, also specify if you are using android or IOS ..etc.

Comment: Badro Niaimi , i have edited the question with further information. Thank you.

Comment: Seems like the OS is aware that this is a touch-screen app.  Strong odds that this is shovelware that came along with the video driver.  You'll have to ask at superuser.com and properly document it, the Windows version and the product name are important.

Comment: Its not the OS knowing that this is a touch-screen app. He does this because i am running the app in a touch-screen .. If i run it on a non touch-screen it will not how the icon. 

And i do not believe it is some sort of a shovelware, but a built in win 7 functionality.  I am afraid that at superuser.com they will completely remove this icon from showing everywhere and i just want to stop it from showing in the app, hence why i asked this in stack.